# Programmatic way to flush DNS in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, dns, flush

I know you can flush the DNS by running `killall -HUP mDNSResponder`, but is there a way to do it in code, without resorting to running a terminal command inside your code? If this exists, would it require permission elevation?

I'm using Swift, so any examples would be preferred in Swift, but I'll do my best to work with whatever you have to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the command using the `system` function:

```
import Foundation

system ("killall -HUP mDNSResponder")
```

Reimplementing `killall` in Swift will be a bit involved; the standard library does not appear to offer something to enumerate system processes.

Comment: Reimplementing killall isn’t something that I’d considered... but that’s probably the only thing that achieves what I need. I’ll look into that!

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future.. you really do just want to call the system utility. There's no benefit to reinventing the wheel here.